# If statement is called from a function and is not being met

Tags: python

I am calling an if statement and condition is met. I am trying to make the if statement update an image however this is not working and im not sure why.

```
attempts = 0

if attempts == 0:
    Hangman = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Images/Hangman0.png"))
    Hangman = Label(image= Hangman)
    Hangman.grid(row=0, column=0)
elif attempts == 1:
    Hangman = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Images/Hangman1.png"))
    Hangman = Label(image= Hangman)
    Hangman.grid(row=0, column=0)

def button_click(letter):
    if letter not in word:
        global attempts
        print("Not in word")
        guessed_letters.add(letter)
        #Add to letters guess
        attempts = attempts+1
        print(attempts)

a = Button(window, text= "a", padx= 10, pady=10, bg= "black", fg= "white", font= ("none", 15), borderwidth=0, command =lambda: button_click("a"))
a.grid(row= 3, column=1)
```

Comment: You can't "call" an `if` statement. Is that code at the top inside a function? If not, it will only run once at the very beginning.

Comment: Sorry as in calling I meant attempts should update from the button_click function which will then cause the if statement, No the code at the top is not inside a function. How would I go about making sure the attempts keeps updating causing the image to change?

Comment: It looks like you want to make the `if/elif` at the top into its own function which is called from `button_click()` just after `attempts = attempts+1`.

Comment: ok, so it looks like if i put **if/elif** in a function and call it after **attempts = atttempts+1** it works. However it is still not changing the image and im not quite sure whats causing it have you got any ideas?

Comment: You may need to use `global Hangman` in the function.

Comment: global Hangman does not change the picture when i put it in the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is limited so I'm guessing a little bit. As the comments mentioned, the if\else statements do not get re-called each time `attempts` changes. You need to put them in a function and call the function each time `attempts` is updated.

Try this:

```
attempts = 0

def CheckAttempts():
    global Hangman, attempts
    if attempts == 0:
        HangmanImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Images/Hangman0.png"))
        Hangman = Label(image= HangmanImg)
        Hangman.grid(row=0, column=0)
    elif attempts == 1:
        HangmanImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Images/Hangman1.png"))
        Hangman = Label(image= HangmanImg)
        Hangman.grid(row=0, column=0)

def button_click(letter):
    if letter not in word:
        global attempts
        print("Not in word")
        guessed_letters.add(letter)
        #Add to letters guess
        attempts = attempts+1
        print(attempts)
     CheckAttempts()

a = Button(window, text= "a", padx= 10, pady=10, bg= "black", fg= "white", font= ("none", 15), borderwidth=0, command =lambda: button_click("a"))
a.grid(row= 3, column=1)
```